# H2 database being populated with incorrect value, but Dev environment works as expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

My Spring Boot application contains some API's which inserts some data into a series of databases.

I am writing automated tests that send input XML's to these API's & populate a H2 (in-memory) database.

All of my tests are running, and the majority of these are running except for some *smalldatetime* fields.

The value that we are expecting to be populating the H2 with is **01/01/1900 00:00:00:000**, but the value that is being populated is **01/01/1970 00:00:00:000**.

Strangely, when I send the same input XML to the Dev environment, the Dev DB is being populated with the correct value (1900)

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

Comment: can you post the code so we can see where the issue is?

Comment: Hi @joemokenela I don't have access to the code at the moment, but I will post it as soon as I do. Based on my own investigating, I think the issue may have something to do with the **Unix epoch date**?

Comment: Sounds like you're inserting 0 into the column. H2 will return this as 01/01/1970 00:00:00:000. Sql server would return it as 01/01/1900 00:00:00:000. You're better using a known date rather than defaulting to 0.